# Need to query list of youtube videos in javascript -- v3 APIs wont work

Tags: javascript, api, video, youtube, google-api

Please forgive me for ranting, this one is giving me a headache...

RANT ON---Great pain with Google programming APIs. Trying to use Google APIs to communicate with YouTube to retrieve a list of my videos. Simple task. Version 2 APIs were easy to use, I had a sample working in 5 minutes. New Version 3 APIs are complex, tedious, require a bunch of advance setup and user account IDs, and after all that hassle, THEY STILL DO NOT WORK.---RANT OFF

C'mon Google, this is really hard to use!

Ok, down to business: I have an API key AND a Client Auth setup.  Neither one works with my efforts to use Google's sample code.

Does anyone have a working sample where JAVASCRIPT in an HTML lists the videos in a YouTube account?  Something where I can just substitute my account id and API key.  Should be very simple, yes?

Thanks in advance for your help... and for bearing with me as I rant...

Answer (score 1):

[This sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#my_uploaded_videos) from the offical docs works just fine. You just need to put your client ID in the `OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID` variable in `auth.js`. Make sure you're using the ID that's in the '**Client ID for web application**' section in the Developers Console.

If you can't get it to work, be more specific about the error you're getting.